# IBM SOLID database ORM

Tags: python, ibm-soliddb

We are working with both IBM Solid and postgres databases.
I am looking for a python ORM that will work with both. 
Could not find any in my searches; only ones that would work with postgres.
Trying to use an ORM which integrates with pyodbc failed on compliance issues.

Comment: Please note: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: We are working with both IBM Solid and postgres databases. I've tried to use sqlalchemy (though it does not support Solid) to try and use its ORM with Solid. Connection with the DB was established but a simple select from one of the tables failed.